k6 - how to use CSV options
I'm new to k6, and am currently looking at how to configure CSV results output. My challenge is that I'm not sure where to set these options.
The documentation says you can configure some things (e.g timestamp) with options: https://k6.io/docs/results-output/real-time/csv/#csv-options
However, I'm not sure where to set these options? I'm aware that you can declare options in an options object, but I'm not sure where in this object you would declare the CSV options? e.g I've tried the below and it does not work:
export const options = {
   timeFormat: "rfc3339_nano"
}

Side note: I have managed to get the CSV options working by setting env vars e.g doing a export K6_CSV_TIME_FORMAT="rfc3339_nano" before running k6. However, I'd prefer to reduce the number of places I'm setting configuration if possible.

Are you looking for a CSV summary or to print the individual datapoints of a metric as CSV? You found the docs for the metrics. Output options cannot be specified via options array, at least not according to the docs. If you are looking for a custom summary, I suggest starting at https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/results-output/end-of-test/custom-summary/

I'm looking for neither of those things. I'm trying to work out where I can set the saveInterval, timeFormat, fileName options. From what I can tell, it's only possible via environment variables, not via an options array.

So you are looking for how to print and format the data points of the metrics. The linked docs and the options are for streaming metric data points to a file. Real time output cannot be specified as part of the options object, but need to be specified via environment variables

export K6_CSV_TIME_FORMAT="rfc3339_nano"
k6 run --out csv=results.csv your_script.js

this is an example how you can run the k6 command with the --out flag

Thanks for the reply. I have done exactly what you have done and it works.
What I'm trying to work out is this: that documentation page I linked mentions a few options (saveInterval, timeFormat, fileName), and from what I can tell these can only be configured by env vars, and not via an options object/options file.
So I'm wondering why the option names are mentioned at all if they can only be configured via env vars. I'm not sure if this is intentional, or an oversight of k6?
